# help with changing point attributes on chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

i have the following chart

[image]

as you can see the points are supposed to be the target for each person, can some one please help me how I may be able to change the attributes for this so that the points are better viable.

also can some one explain why on the chart there are four columns and its only showing 2 peoples name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the size of the points bigger 
`Chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerSize = 15;`
but in my opinion you should go with a 2D with your combinational chart or play with 3D point gap and depth & perspective for easy read.

it seems you have more xy points than two but it's hard to tell without seeing your data and how you set the X axis interval.